# Primary key not unique in SQLLite with AutoIncrement

Tags: java, sqlite

I've created a table with an autoincrement primary key:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY " + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + " NAME TEXT NOT NULL)"
```

Next, I want to add a record to my database.

However, when I run program I get the message:

> A PRIMARY KEY constraint failed (UNIQUE constraint failed: COMPANY.ID).

Any ideas how I can auto increment a record number? I'm not editing existing records I'm adding a record.  To insert into company values I used the term "active" in the ID field.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nam;
        int ag;
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nEnter your name : ");
        nam = key.next();
        System.out.println("\nEnter your age : ");
        ag = key.nextInt();


        Connection c = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

            stmt = c.createStatement();

            String sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES(" + active + " ,
            '" + nam + "', " + ag + ")"; 
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            c.commit();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM COMPANY;"
           );
            while ( rs.next() ) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String  name = rs.getString("name");
                int age  = rs.getInt("age");
                System.out.println( "ID = " + id );
                System.out.println( "NAME = " + name );
                System.out.println( "AGE = " + age );
                System.out.println();
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            c.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + 
       e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Operation done successfully");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually did specify the auto increment? My guess is that your query tries to insert `NULL` as primary key (which is permitted by SQLite) each time, resulting in duplicate primary key. You could dump your DB to see what's actually in it

Comment: My query is: String sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY " +
                   "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY     AUTOINCREMENT," +
                   " NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL)"        // This works to compile records but not to add record to existing database.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not input the id. It's assigned by the database.

Second, I am pretty sure you need to specify the columns explicitly when you insert into autoincrement table:

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY (name, age) VALUES(?, ?)
```

Note that your CREATE TABLE statement does not match your INSERT statement.

Finally, please look up "SQL injection". Use prepared statements rather than string concatenation

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I inserted NULL in value for id and to add record number was automatically created.  I am reading "SDQL injection" to learn prepared statements.